# Configuring fluxbox (or any other WM) on FreeBSD

Tags: xorg, freebsd, login, fluxbox, xinit

First time using FreeBSD (or any BSD).
I recently installed FreeBSD and installed xorg and fluxbox with:

```
pkg install xorg fluxbox
```

And put this in the `.xinitrc` for my user:

```
exec xterm &
exec fluxbox
```

Now I get the login screen but when I enter my username and password, after a brief pause I am returned to the login screen without any error shown. Also I am unable to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or other terminals; I have to use ssh to login to the system. Is there some step I am missing, or I need to debug it, if yes then how?

**EDIT:**
I installed slim with `pkg install slim` and put `slim_enable="YES"` in /etc/rc.conf but the login screen I get is still the old one and I'm still unable to login.

Comment: What do you mean, "I am unable to use Ctrl+Alt+F1 or other terminals"?  What happens when you try?

Comment: It remains on the same login screen instead of switching to a console.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `.xinitrc` to just

```
xterm &
fluxbox &
```

or

```
xterm &
exec fluxbox
```

Comment: I changed it to
`xterm &
exec fluxbox`

Still the same. There's a line break after xterm &

Answer (score 0):

The issue with

```
exec xterm &
exec fluxbox
```

is that the first `exec` will *replace* the script with an `xterm` process.  This means that the second `exec` will never run.

You probably want to do something like

```
startfuxbox &
```

or

```
exec startfluxbox
```

instead.

I'm not a fluxbox user, but I imagine that `xterm` may be started from within the window manager, and be made to automatically start by it too.  If not, add `xterm &` on the line before the `exec`.